# How to change the selected row background color in Pyside?

Tags: pyside, qtgui

How do I change the background color of the 'selected' row in a PySide table widget from the default color? (Preferable the *style* remains the same, just the color scheme changes.)

Perhaps not possible on Linux due to bug:
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-34158

Answer (score 0):

Set the `selection-background-color` property. [style sheet reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#selection-background-color-prop)

From the [style sheet examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html) quite at the bottom:

QTableView { selection-background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0.5, y2: 0.5,  stop: 0 #FF92BB, stop: 1 white); }

Comment: It's interesting that 'selection-color' works in changing the colour of the text in the selected row, but 'selection-background-color' for either QTableView or QTableWidget does not work for changing the background colour. I'm still trying to figure out how to make it work.